# Stop calling overloaded new and delete operator by stl containers

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading, instrumentation

I am developing a memoryleak tool. In this i am overloading new and delete operator. Its working fine. But the code for which i am creating this tool is around 15000 lines. I cannot change the existing code only i can invoke the memoryleak tool function into the existing code. Existing code having stl containers (like list, map, stack etc). Stl container also call new and delete operator to allocate or deallocate memory. i want that stl container should call the new and delete operator which are in  not the overloaded new and delete.
for ex:

```
int *iptr = new int[10] ----> should call overloaded new[]
delete [] iptr -------------> should call overloaded delete[]
map.insert(10) -------------> should call default new[] ( which are in new.h)
map.erase()  ---------------> should call default delete[] ( which are in new.h)
```

how can i do it?
Any help would be aprreciated.

Sorry i forgot to mention that i am replacing new and delete with the following macros:

```
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#define DEBUG_NEW TrackMemory(__FILE__, __LINE__) ->* new
#define delete TrackDelete(__FILE__, __LINE__); delete
```

here TrackMemory is used to track memory and new is used to allocate memory same with delete.
my tool also works fine but when stl containers comes into picture then it gives wrong result because they only use overloaded new.
please help me out

Comment: why are you re-inventing the wheel? There already lots of very good tools for this (such as Valgrind etc.)

Comment: maybe he is using the windows API?

Answer (score 3):

Starting by writing these 'empty' functions.  They will replace the standard new and delete by your own:

```
void *operator new (size_t memorySize);
void *operator new[] (size_t memorySize);
void *operator new (size_t memorySize, const std::nothrow_t &) throw ();
void *operator new[] (size_t memorySize, const std::nothrow_t &) throw ();
void operator delete (void *memoryPointer);
void operator delete[] (void *memoryPointer);
void operator delete (void *memoryPointer, const std::nothrow_t &) throw ();
void operator delete[] (void *memoryPointer, const std::nothrow_t &) throw ();
```

Then write separate functions to allocate and deallocate memory:

```
void *myNew (size-t memorySize);
void myDelete (void *memoryPointer);
```

Call your myNew and myDelete in the functions mentioned in the beginning.

Implement myNew and myDelete by using HeapAlloc and HeapFree.

Then make a global variable and mark it like this (this is Visual Studio):

```
#pragma init_seg(lib)
```

This will make sure your global variable is initialized first, and cleaned up last.

So far, we have covered the basis.  To get real leak-reporting-functionality, you will need to store information about allocated memory in your myNew function.

Use the destructor of your global variable to report all leaks.

Additionally, you could use StackWalk to get the call stack and also store this with each memory allocation.

Some will probably wonder why you want to do this instead of using other tools:

- in my experience, leak reporting in Visual Studio is limited.  It doesn't show you the call stack, but only the direct caller, which makes it meaningless.
- some tools use #define to replace new, delete, alloc, ..., but this can gives problems in quite some cases (e.g. a class method which is called free (seen this in Qt), or the delete is done in a header, but a new in a .lib which must be linked in (also seen in Qt)).
- other tools require you to make interactive snapshots of your application and compare them afterwards.  In my approach above, you get automatic leak reporting (no manual action needed, always at end of the application, ...).

Once you have your own memory manager, you can start thinking about adding other functionality (e.g. memory statistics based on the call stack, tricks to find memory overwrites, tricks to find code that reuses memory after it has been deleted, ...).

Comment: Hi Patrick,
Thanks for replying. I think your suggessted way won't be able to stop calling our overloaded new and delete operator by stl containers.

Comment: That's true, but by replacing the global new and delete operators, you are guaranteed that the whole of STL is also using them, and you can use this to have better memory leak reporting, or making statistics about who is using how much memory.

Answer (score 2):

15000 lines ? Well, replace all calls to `new` and `delete` by calls to wrapper methods in your code (using macros to log `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` can be a first step) and you'll be done quickly.

Or use an existing tool, like *valgrind*.

Comment: This way, you will miss all the allocations made by the STL.  It's better to replace the global new/delete by your own implementations.

Comment: @Patrick: it's precisely what the OP asked for, simply assuming that his STL is working I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by saying you're overloading operator new. You cannot overload the standard operator new as such, you can only replace it at link time. When you replace it you lose the original ones, which is the stupidest design I have ever seen. The replacement is also global. You can work around this with platform specific linker tricks on some platforms (weak symbols).

You can do some kind of lookup tricks with class based operator new, and of course you can overload operator new on placement arguments, but I assume you mean neither of these.

Comment: actually you can provide your own definition or `new` and `delete` in which case the compiler will use yours instead of the default ones. Or am I mistaken ?

Comment: Replacing the standard new and delete by your own implementations isn't utterly stupid at all.  In fact it's the best way to do it if you want to write your own memory allocator or you want to use another one (like DougLea's one), AND you dont' want to use platform-specific tricks like changing the DLL entry tables (trampolines, ...).

Comment: @Matthieu: your are absolutely right but this thing i have to stop. i just want that stl containers should use default new and delete operator instead of mine.